# Using presentShareDialogWithLink method of FBDialogs ignores description parameter ios

Tags: ios, fbdialogs, facebook-share

I am using FBDialogs to share on facebook where I am sharing picture, name and description.
Below is my code used for sharing:-

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                     name:params.name
                                  caption:nil
                                  description:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OMG I’m in LOVE with a puppy named %@.Come and say hi %@",sPuppyName , ITUNES_STORE_LINK]
                                  picture:params.picture
                              clientState:nil
                                  handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                      if(error) {
                                          // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                          // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                          NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                      } else {
                                          // Success

                                          NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                          NSLog(@"result obtained %@",[results valueForKey:@"completionGesture"]);
                                          if([[results valueForKey:@"completionGesture"] isEqualToString:@"cancel"]){

                                         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"facebookDidSharingCancel" object:self userInfo:nil];
                                          }
                                          else if([[results valueForKey:@"completionGesture"] isEqualToString:@"post"])
                                        {
                                               [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"facebookDidLogin" object:self userInfo:nil];

                                          }  
                                      }
                                  }];
```

I am able to see description on share dialog while sharing but on Facebook site I am not able to see description.
Searched a lot but cant find any way so please anybody help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try it by removing that ITUNES_STORE_LINK ? (i.e do not pass link just plain text)

Comment: Yes i had tried every possible ways even i tried by writing "hello" message to share but it didnt get shared